# Want to use "delegate" function of jQuery instead of click in this code... unable to do so...

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, delegates, click

Inorder to speed up the app I am trying to use a delegate function instead of the click function... but due to some reasons I am unable to even enter the function....

Any help??

Here is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/checkbox.css"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.css" />

        <title>Subscribe</title>
        <script src="scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

**Want to use Delegate instead of Click**
                   $('#selectAllTechAreas').click(function(){
                    //alert('aaa');
                      $('.techAreasCheckBox').attr('checked', true);
                    }); // Tech Areas Select All click function

                    $('#selectAllAssetTypes').tap(function(event){
                            $('.assetTypeCheckBox').attr('checked', true);
                    }); // Asset Types Select All click function
                    $('#clearAllSelections').click(function(){
                        $('.assetTypeCheckBox').attr('checked', false);
                        $('.techAreasCheckBox').attr('checked', false);
                    });
            }); // document
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div data-role="content" class="contentGrayBg">
            <div id="categoriesTable">
                </table>
                <br>

                <div class="container">
                        <div class="floatLeft">
                                <table id="technologyAreas">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <fieldset id="techAreasCB" data-role="controlgroup">
                                            <legend style="font-style: bold; font-size:16px">Technology Areas:</legend>
                                                <table>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td><input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" class="case techAreasCheckBox" /></td>
                                                        <td style="padding-left: 40px">SAP</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td><input type="checkbox" data-mini="true" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" class="case techAreasCheckBox" /></td>
                                                        <td style="padding-left: 40px">Oracle</td>
                                                    </tr>

                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td><!-- <input type="checkbox" id="selectAllTechAreas"/> --></td>
                                                        <td >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label id="selectAllTechAreas" style="color: orange; padding-left: 10px"><b>Select All</b></label></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>        
                                            </fieldset>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                        </div>  <!-- Div Class Float Left -->


                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 

    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks,
Ankit.

Comment: Since you're using jQuery 1.8 you should be using `on` and `prop`. Check them out on the jQuery API.

Comment: Show us the JS where you tried to use `on`; seeing your entire HTML document from the doctype to the closing `html` tag is unnecessary

Comment: Hi elclanrs... but the delegate function is also there I think... am I right?? or have they removed delegate function totally?

Comment: @Asad I havent used on property... I've only used click... but I wanna use delegate instead...

Comment: @AnkitTanna the `delegate` method is still present, but `on` is favored.

Comment: the difference: delegate asigns the event to the context... i.e. the tag only and not the root... where as click/on has some performance issues with large selections... :( @JanDvorak

Comment: @AnkitTanna you can delegate with `on`. The selection itself is then very small.

Comment: You are using an ID selector which is incredibly fast and only selects one element ever (because IDs must be unique). There is **absolutely no reason** to use delegates for performance. Using one, possible even with `document` as the reference element, is likely to make it slower because now jQuery needs to check *every single* click event to see if the source element matches your selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For purposes of generality I am going to assume you want to delegate to the document:

```
$(document).on('click','#selectAllTechAreas',function(){
        $('.techAreasCheckBox').attr('checked', true);
        // ...
});
```

Generally, the pattern followed is:

```
$(document).on('click','#selectAllTechAreas',function(){
-----------    -------  -------------------  -----------
     |            |               |                |
element you     event  selector that specifies  your handler
want to          type    which elements to
delegate to             fire the handler for
```

To be clear here, I am not advocating that you delegate your handler to the document, or even to any ancestor, since your target is a single element (particularly since you seem to not be entirely clear on the utility of delegation). I recommend reading [this article](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) to get a better handle on the subject.

To elaborate on the motivation behind delegation, and why it is pointless to delegate the event for a single element, consider the following:

```
<ul id="parent-list">
  <li id="post-1">Item 1</li>
  <li id="post-2">Item 2</li>
  <li id="post-3">Item 3</li>
  <li id="post-4">Item 4</li>
  <li id="post-5">Item 5</li>
  <li id="post-6">Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

Say I wanted to attach a click event for every list item. I would end up having to attach 6 event handlers like so:

```
$('li').click(function(){
    alert('clicked!');
});
```

Behind the scenes, jQuery is iterating over each `li` and attaching that event handler for it. It would be nice if there was a less wasteful way to do this...

This is where delegation comes in. I can attach just one handler to the `ul`, which checks whether the target of the event matches the selector `li`, before firing the event handler:

```
$('ul').on("click","li",function(){
    alert('clicked!');
});
```

This is more efficient than maintaining 6 separate identical event handlers.

Now let us look at your case. In your case, you want to attach an event handler to `#post-1`. The most efficient way to do this is simply to attach an event handler to `#post-1` directly, since you aren't making any savings by attaching to the parent.

There aren't 6 separate `#post-1` elements you need to attach the handler to, so there is no point in delegating the event.

Comment: Thanks asad.. but I tried that earlier.. this is where the performance factor comes... joining events to the document makes it hectic and time consuming.... where as if the event is bound to the "Select All" Tag itself then its way faster...

Comment: @AnkitTanna I disagree. Your bottleneck must lie elsewhere.

Comment: @AnkitTanna You don't need to bind to the document, the only reason I did is because you did not specify which element you want to delegate to.

Comment: @Asad is this equivalent to delegate... cause when we see with fire query in Firefox... the event gets attached to the element itself to the element only and not the document... and one more question... what if I want to delegate it to "selectAllTechAreas" only?

Comment: @AnkitTanna It seems you are misunderstanding what delegation is. There is, by definition, no way to delegate the event handling for an element *to itself*. That makes no sense whatsoever. Delegation is when you attach a handler for a bunch of elements to a common ancestor, which checks if the target fulfills certain criteria before firing the handler.

Comment: @Asad I specifically want to get the function running on the click on "select all" label... what I am trying to avoid is getting events cluttered under root/document...

Comment: oh... we cannot get delegate to and element itself?? :! sorry for the misunderstanding...

Comment: oh... okay... that means to the parent of the "select all" label??

Comment: Asad, does that mean... that the handler comes under the "document" or the delegated element?

Comment: @Asad what's the point of using delegation on a single element? (#selectAllTechAreas)

Comment: @AnkitTanna What does delegating to itself even mean? Delegation is just the approach of attaching the handler for some elements to an ancestor, instead of to the elements themselves.

Comment: okay @asad I got your point... :) so what I should be doing is instead on "document" in Asad's answer, I shall be writing the immediate parent element of the "Select All" label... so the handler goes under the Parent of the "Select All" Label and the application would work faster...

Comment: @Asad well, why are you proposing this as answer if it is pointless?

Comment: @Christophe I got asad's point... what happens is the element goes and looks for its handler from inner most level to the top document root... so if the element gets the handler in the very first level it can reduce the search time for the handler :)

Comment: @Christophe Because that is what the OP asked for. It is not a pointless answer; the OP asked how he could delegate an event handler using jQuery and I showed him how. Whether he *should* in this circumstance is a different question altogether, which I have also briefly addressed.

Comment: AnkitTanna I don't think you understand. The correct answer is the comment posted by @ThiefMaster.

Comment: @Christophe I've expanded on my answer. Does this address your concerns?

Comment: @Asad I have seen this... but please tell me... I I want my parent(delegated) tag to be <td> and its child tag to be Select All.... its not working....

Comment: @Asad it definitely helps, especially as the OP was obviously not understanding the point of delegating.